# Analysis of the function $\prod_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2} })$

Tags: reference-request

While playing on pruduct series, I noticed interesting function that it has similar behavior to $C\cdot\sin^2(\pi x)$ function . I need help about some results below.

$$f(x)=\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}}) $$  where $a>0$

The function is a periodic function because

$$f(x+1)=\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(1-e^{-a{(x+1+n)^2}}) =\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}}) $$

Some properties of the function:

---

- $f(x+1)=f(x)$  Period is $1$
- It is obvious that $f(k)=0$ where $k$ is integer.
- It is even function. $f(-x)=f(x)$

These properties above are same as $C.\sin^2(\pi x)$

My ideas and my aim to find out about the function are

1. Can we express it as known functions?
2. How closed form of $f(\frac{1}{2})$ can be found? I believe  that the function behaves the same as $C\sin^2(\pi x)$ has and $f'(\frac{1}{2})=0$ but I could not prove it.
3. If it is a periodic function, what is the Fourier series expansion of the function?

Any reference links about the function and help will be appreciated very much .

Thanks

UPDATE: I proved my conjecture above , $f'(\frac{1}{2})=0$

I added some extra information too

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=2a\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty } \frac{x+n}{e^{a{(x+n)^2}}-1} $$

$$\frac{f'(\frac{1}{2})}{f(\frac{1}{2})}=2a\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty } \frac{\frac{1}{2}+n}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+n)^2}}-1} $$

$$\frac{f'(\frac{1}{2})}{f(\frac{1}{2})}=a\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty } \frac{2n+1}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+n)^2}}-1}$$

$$f'(\frac{1}{2})=af(\frac{1}{2})\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty } \frac{2n+1}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+n)^2}}-1}$$

$$f'(\frac{1}{2})=af(\frac{1}{2})\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ -1 } \frac{2n+1}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+n)^2}}-1}+af(\frac{1}{2})\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac{2n+1}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+n)^2}}-1}$$

$$f'(\frac{1}{2})=af(\frac{1}{2})\sum\limits_{k=0}^{  \infty } \frac{-(2k+1)}{e^{a{(-1)^2(\frac{1}{2}+k)^2}}-1}+af(\frac{1}{2})\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac{2n+1}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+n)^2}}-1}$$

$$f'(\frac{1}{2})=-af(\frac{1}{2})\sum\limits_{k=0}^{  \infty } \frac{2k+1}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+k)^2}}-1}+af(\frac{1}{2})\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac{2n+1}{e^{a{(\frac{1}{2}+n)^2}}-1}$$

$$f'(\frac{1}{2})=0$$

There can be proved in same way that

$f'(\frac{2k+1}{2})=0$ where $k$ is integer.

UPDATE: Nov 13th

I tried to used roots of $1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}}$ . I would like to share my results. Maybe it can be helpful to find out an expression with known functions.

$$1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}}=0$$
roots are:

$$a{(x+n)^2}=2k\pi i$$  Where $k$ integer.

If $k=0$

Roots  $x=-n$  where $n$ is integer as known. 
for $k=0$ and They are double roots ,Thus

$$\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}}=x^2\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})^2\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }G(x,a)$$

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2 (\pi x)}{\pi^2}\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }G(x,a)$$

$\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }G(x,a)$ will be expressed by other roots for $k\neq 0$

$$\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }G(x,a)=\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }\prod\limits_{k=1}^{ \infty }(1-\frac{x}{-n+\sqrt{\frac{2k \pi i }{a}}})(1-\frac{x}{-n-\sqrt{\frac{2k \pi i }{a}}})(1-\frac{x}{-n+\sqrt{\frac{-2k \pi i }{a}}})(1-\frac{x}{-n-\sqrt{\frac{-2k \pi i }{a}}})$$

$$\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }G(x,a)=\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }\prod\limits_{k=1}^{ \infty }(1+\frac{2nx}{n^2-\frac{2k \pi i }{a}}+\frac{x^2}{n^2-\frac{2k \pi i }{a}})(1+\frac{2nx}{n^2+\frac{2k \pi i }{a}}+\frac{x^2}{n^2+\frac{2k \pi i }{a}})$$

$$\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }G(x,a)=\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }\prod\limits_{k=1}^{ \infty }(\frac{(x+n)^2-\frac{2k \pi i }{a}}{n^2-\frac{2k \pi i }{a}})(\frac{(x+n)^2+\frac{2k \pi i }{a}}{n^2+\frac{2k \pi i }{a}})$$

So finally we can write ;

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2 (\pi x)}{\pi^2}\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }\prod\limits_{k=1}^{ \infty }(\frac{(x+n)^4+\frac{4\pi^2 k^2 }{a^2}}{n^4+\frac{4 \pi^2 k^2  }{a^2}})$$

I thought to change product order can help us, so to get

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2 (\pi x)}{\pi^2}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{ \infty }\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(\frac{(x+n)^4+\frac{4\pi^2 k^2 }{a^2}}{n^4+\frac{4 \pi^2 k^2  }{a^2}})$$

I am till here for now, But I do not see how to go from here to get a nice expression with known functions.

Thanks for helps

EDIT: 1/9/2017

After @Yuriy S 's wonderful graphics, I realized that we may express the $f(x,a)$ in approximation.

$$f(x,a)=\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}}) $$  where $a>0$

Known values of $f(x,a)$:

1. $f(x,0)=0$
2. $\lim_{a\to\infty} f(x,a)=1$
3. $f(1/2+k,a)$ has maximum, where $k$ is integer
4. $f(k,a)=0$, where $k$ is integer
5. $f(x,a)$ is periodic function over $x$

I conjecture   that $f(x,a) \approx \cfrac{a^k \sin^2(\pi x)}{a^k \sin^2(\pi x)+c}$ ,where $a>0$, $k,c$ are positive real numbers,

From Graphics below, I calculated  $k$ and $c$.

in sixth graph,

$$f(1/2,1)\approx 0.04$$
$$f(1/2,0.6)\approx 0.01$$

From these results, I got $k$ and $c$.

$k \approx 2.774$ and $c \approx 24$.

Maybe someone can help me to calculate  $k$ and $c$ more accurately.

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: $f'\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)=0$ just follows from $f(x)=f(1-x)=f(1+x)$.

Comment: I will check my code and post again. Sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention to your theoretical analysis! I will remove my old comment.

Comment: @sonystarmap  Thanks a lot.

Comment: My code had $(1+exp)$ instead of $(1-exp)$. [Here](http://imgur.com/bgtC3nZ) is the correction. $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(0.5)$ is maximal. Larger bumps for larger vales of $a$.

Comment: @sonystarmap Wonderful result. Exactly As I expected in theory. I wonder if the function can be expressed as f(x)=A(a)sin2πx or not. I mean if G(x,a) does not to depend on x . I try to prove or disprove it now. Maybe you can help me via Matlab codes draw G(x,a).Is it possible depends on only a ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you might be missing exponential factors in your $G(x,a)$ function.

Comment: @AleksVlasev  Could you please give more detail? Thanks

Comment: I once asked [a related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891974/why-is-sum-n-infty-infty-exp-xn2-almost-constant), take a log and copy the idea in the answer, you can get an expression for the Fourier series expansion(for the log function). I can only express the coefficients in terms of infinite sums, but I am not good at this, maybe you can get more

Comment: @Mathlover, yea. So, if you compute the order $\rho$ of the the function $1-\exp(-ax^2)$ you will find that it is $\rho = 2$ which means that the weierstrass factorization of the functions $1-\exp(-a(x+n)^2)$ will have an exponential term $\exp(x/x_k+x^2/x_k^2)$ associated with each zero $x_k$. Combining the $\pm$ roots together with the $+k$ and $-k$ gets rid of the linear part but still leaves an $\exp(Cx^2)$ factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this answer separately, so that the analytics are not lost among the illustrative material from my first post.

> This answer deals with Fourier series, not for the function $f(x)$ itself, but for its logarithm.

It's often easier to deal with the logarithms of infinite products, since they are represented as infinite series.

$$\ln f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \ln(1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}})=$$

Since $a(x+n)^2>0$ we can always expand the logarithm into its Taylor series:

$$=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} e^{-ka(x+n)^2}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} e^{-kax^2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-kan(n+2x)}$$

The latter sum fits the definition of a [Jacobi Theta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_3$, thus:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-kan(n+2x)}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{ka}} e^{kax^2} \vartheta_3 \left(\pi x, e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{ka}}\right)$$

This result is confirmed by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BExp%5B-k+a+n(n%2B2+x)%5D,%7Bn,-Infinity,Infinity%7D%5D).

This looks complicated, but there is another series representation for $\vartheta_3$ which might help:

$$\vartheta_3 \left(\pi x, e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{ka}}\right)=1+2\sum_{l=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{\pi^2l^2}{ka}} \cos(2 \pi l x)$$

Now we obtain:

$$\ln f(x)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} \left(1+2\sum_{l=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{\pi^2l^2}{ka}} \cos(2 \pi l x)  \right)$$

And finally:

$$\ln f(x)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \zeta \left( \frac32 \right) -2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \sum_{l=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} e^{-\pi^2l^2/(ka)} \cos(2 \pi l x)$$

Or, introducing:

> $$C_l (a)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} e^{-\pi^2l^2/(ka)}$$

The familiar form of a Fourier series emerges (with the first term being the constant term $l=0$):

> $$\ln f(x)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \zeta \left( \frac32 \right) -2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \sum_{l=1}^\infty C_l (a) \cos(2 \pi l x)$$

The convergence is not very good, however the $l$ sum converges much faster than the $k$ sum (which should be obvious by looking at the exponential term in $C_l$). Thus, we don't need a lot of Fourier terms, but the coefficients have to be computed precisely.

Here is an illustration for $a=1$:

[image]

---

This Fourier series allows us excellent insight into similarities with the $C \sin^2 (\pi x)$ function.

$$\frac{(\sin^2 (\pi x))'}{\sin^2 (\pi x)}=2 \pi \cot (\pi x)$$

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=(\ln f(x))'=4 \pi \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \sum_{l=1}^\infty l~C_l \sin(2 \pi l x)$$

It turns out, these new functions are very close for $a=1$ (if we compute $C_l$ accurately enough):

[image]

However, there is a correlation - the larger $a$, the faster $k$-sum converges, but the slower $l$-sum converges. Thus, if $a$ is small you need to take more terms in $k$-sum, but if $a$ is large you ned to take more terms in the $l$-sum.

Here are plots for the same large number of terms for $a=0.2,1,5$:

[image]

---

**Disclaimer**

The Fourier series has been introduced in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/892009/269624), I have not seen it before writing my own, even though it's linked above in the comments to the OP. I acknowledge that Semiclassical got there first.

Comment: Thanks for beautiful relations and results. To use cos series representation of Jacobi Theta function is very good idea. I liked it.  When I check your graphs,  Is it correct that $2 \pi \cot(\pi x)$ upper limit for $f'(x)/f(x)$ for any $a$ and $x$.? Best Regards

Comment: @Mathlover, for $x \in (0,1/2)$ it seems so, however I wouldn't be certain. I suggest you obtain the analytical expression for the Fourier series of $\cot (\pi x)$ and compare the coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

**It's not an answer, but there are a lot of graphs which can't be put into a comment.**

The function $\prod\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(1-e^{-a{(x+n)^2}})$ is very close to $C \sin^2(\pi x)$ for $a \leq 1$, as can be seen by numerical experiments:

1) For $a=1$ the scaling constant $C=0.0390070548953618...$ and the functions are practically indistinguishable.

[image]

2) For $a<<1$ the functions are also very close with appropriate scaling.

[image]

3) However, for $a>>1$ the functions are different, since $f(x)$ approaches a constant around its maxima.

[image]

[image]

---

The overall $a$ dependence can be seen in the following 3D graph and the $f(1/2)$ graphs for the dependence around a maximum. The latter has the character of a logistic function.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I didn't have much luck with analytics so far, but I will expand my post into a proper answer if something useful comes up.

---

Update. As asked by the OP, I tested their approximation, it's not very good:

[image]

Comment: Hello Yuriy, Thank you so much for your great graphics. I could see the picture of the function better . I  estimated an approximation for the function after graphs. Could you please analyze the approximation that I put in end of  my question with your tools how it is near the exact $f(x,a)$?  By the way, It can need better $k,c$  values , because I calculated them from your graph.  Thanks a lot again for your contribution .

Comment: @Mathlover, thank you. Once I'm home in a few hours, I'll try to calculate your $k,c$ values with Mathematica. However, in general I would advise you to use some mathematical software yourself, since it would make your research much more efficient. There are free programs as well, such as Sage (or Python libraries).

Comment: Thank you for the advice .  I will check them.

Comment: @Mathlover, sorry, your approximation is not correct for $1<a<10$ - there is a very large discrepancy. Changing the parameters doesn't help much, at least as far as I see - it's not enough to achieve good agreement for every value of $a$. I would suggest trying something analytically as you've been doing. I have some ideas as well, maybe something will work

Comment: Thanks a lot for feedback. I have been thinking on $1<a<10$, I will consider analytically what It needs. . Could you please add your results in your answer? It can be very helpful for me and  community.. Best Regards

Comment: @Mathlover, I've tried to compute the values of $f(1/2,a)$ precisely, but there is something wrong with Mathematica. I will post them once I'm sure I got the correct ones.