# How to estimate a specific infinite sum

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, theta-functions

Let $M$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix with each diagonal element equal to $k$ and each non-diagonal element equal to $k-1$ where $n$ and $k$ are positive integers. Let $k < n$ and we can assume both $k$ and $n$ are large.

What is

$$S_{M,k} = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^T M x}\;?$$

Is there some way to estimate this sum?

---

**Update April 21 2016**

Hajo argues below that $S_{M,k} \leq S_{M,1} = (\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2})^n$.  This bound may however be loose when $k \gg 1$.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/236572/how-to-estimate-a-specific-infinite-sum .

Answer (score 0):

We can write 
$$M=I+(k-1)ee^\top \text{ with } e=(1,\ldots,1)^\top$$
so we get the eigenvalues 
$$ \lambda_1=1,\ldots,\lambda_{n-1}=1,\lambda_n=n(k-1)+1$$ 
to the orthonormal eigenvectors 
$$v_1,\ldots,v_n \text{ with } v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e\text{.}$$
We can write the term from the exponent as 
$$x^\top Mx=x^\top x + (k-1)(x^\top e)(e^\top x)$$
Plugged in the given term
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} = \sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} \exp \bigl(-(\lVert x\rVert_2^2 + (k-1)(x^\top e)^2 )\bigr)$$ 
now we decompose $\mathbb{Z}^n$ into surfaces of hypercubes with help of $\lVert x\rVert_\infty = \max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\lvert x_i\rvert$.

$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} = e^0 + \sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{\stackrel{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n}{\lVert x\rVert_\infty=r}} \exp \bigl(-(\lVert x\rVert_2^2 + (k-1)(x^\top e)^2 )\bigr)\text{.}$$
To get a estimation from above, we use the eigenvector (independent from $k$)
$$v=(r,-r,0,\ldots,0) \text{ with } v^\top Mv=2r^2$$ with the smallest 2-norm to the smallest eigenvalue $1$, and get
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} \leq e^0 + \sum_{r=1}^\infty\Bigl\lvert\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n\big\vert\lVert x\rVert_\infty=r\}\Bigr\rvert e^{-2r^2}\text{.}$$
The number of point in this set is the number of points in the full hypercube minus the number of points of the smaller hypercube
$$\Bigl\lvert\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n\big\vert\lVert x\rVert_\infty=r\}\Bigr\rvert=(2r+1)^n-(2(r-1)+1)^n=(2r+1)^n-(2r-1)^n$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} \leq 1 + \sum_{r=1}^\infty \bigl((2r+1)^n-(2r-1)^n\bigr)e^{-2r^2}\text{.}$$
Similarly, we can use the eigenvector 
$$v=(r,\ldots,r) \text{ with } v^\top Mv=nr^2+(k-1)(nr)^2=nr^2(1+n(k-1))$$ with the biggest 2-norm to the biggest eigenvalue $\lambda_n=n(k-1)+1$ to get an estimate from below
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} \geq 1 + \sum_{r=1}^\infty \bigl((2r+1)^n-(2r-1)^n\bigr)\exp\bigl(-nr^2(1+n(k-1))\bigr)\text{.}$$

---

Added: For a upper bound we use $(k-1)(x^\top e)^2 \geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}^n$, together with $\lVert x\rVert_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ and $e^{a+b}=e^a\cdot e^b$ to get
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} \leq \sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-x_i^2}=\sum_{x_1\in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{x_2\in \mathbb{Z}}\cdots \sum_{x_n\in \mathbb{Z}}\prod_{i=1}^n e^{-x_i^2}=\sum_{x_1\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-x_1^2} \sum_{x_2\in \mathbb{Z}}\cdots \sum_{x_n\in \mathbb{Z}}\prod_{i=2}^n e^{-x_i^2}\text{.}$$
Thus, we have an upper bound
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} \leq \Bigl(\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-x^2}\Bigr)^n$$
And with help of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/892009) we get 
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^\top M x} \leq \Bigl(\sqrt{\pi}+2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\exp(-m^2\pi^2) \Bigr)^n\text{.}$$
The estimate is again independent from $k$ but should be sharp/exact for $k=1$. ($k=1\Rightarrow M=I$)

Comment: added eigenvalues, because i can't comment on math overflow. Added some estimate.

Comment: I think the correct answer for $n=10, k=5$ is approx. $56.564$ .

Comment: However, your upper bound for $n=10,k=5$ is around $1+ 11251.62470$ and your lower bound is around $1+0.5134138876*10^{-173}$.

Comment: @Anush For convenience of the community, you could add your source code to your question or as an answer. Also, you could ask more precisely what kind of estimates you need.

Comment: I used Mathematica. `SiegelTheta[I*p/Pi, ConstantArray[0, Length@p]]` where `p` is the matrix.  Unfortunately this is very slow for anything but small matrices. In fact $n=10$ is about the maximum you can realistically do.

Comment: An estimate that is correct within a constant multiplicative factor (say a factor of 2) would be great but I am not sure what is achievable.