# Prove this exponential/cosine relation?

Tags: summation, exponential-function, exponential-sum

This seems correct numerically, but my efforts at a proof have not succeeded.

$$f(x)\equiv\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-n)^{2}}$$
Prove
$$f(x)-\sqrt{\pi}=(f(0)-\sqrt{\pi})\cos(2\pi x)$$
Bonus points for the simplest proof.

Comment: It's a theta function; your formula will only be approximate, not exact, but to obtain it think Fourier series and Poisson summation.

Comment: It's not true. $f(x)$ is an even periodic function with period $1$, so it has a Fourier series. Just the coefficients are $O(e^{-An^2})$, so numerically, only the first two, essentially $\sqrt{\pi}$ and the (small) $f(0)-\sqrt{\pi}$, play a role.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Yes, this involves a theta function, but I deliberately posed the question to factor out the theta function and focus everyone's helpful efforts on the cosine.

Comment: @ProfessorVector  Is it possible the higher Fourier terms vanish?

Comment: A related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891974/269624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/892009/269624):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-n)^2}
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+n)^2}
= \sqrt{\pi}+2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k^2 \pi^2}\cos 2\pi kx$$

Thus:

$$f(x)-\sqrt{\pi}=2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k^2 \pi^2}\cos 2\pi kx$$

$$f(0)-\sqrt{\pi}=2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k^2 \pi^2}$$

It seems your relation is not correct.

Comment: In other words, $f(x)=\sqrt{\pi}\theta_3(\pi x,e^{-\pi^2}).$